# Display amount of specific rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I have literally searched for this in hours. I very new to PHP, so i dont understand what and why i am doing something wrong.
Here's what i want:
Let's say i have this table:

```
Player    |online
----------|------
Max       |  0
Jacob     |  1
Peter     |  1
Jørgen    |  1
osborne   |  0
Jimmy     |  1
```

I want a script that would print out the amount of rows with "1" in online, so it would write the number "4" (in this case) on my website.

How do i do this? Please post complete script, as i am a complete newbie to this :s

Comment: He never asked us how to make it for him... He just wanted to know how to get the number of rows dude. EDIT: Oh, "please post complete script". Sorry, didn't read that part.

Comment: @op : below is code to find out the number of online users, you should  query the database in PHP and then fetch the result, post code in case it doesn't work ... read more on http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: So I wonder how you would flag this question ;)

Comment: Heres the one i tried then gave up:
            <?php
$link = mysql_connect('deltacraft.me', 'deltacra_root', 'ento34');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


// Select data from database
$do_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online_players WHERE  online = 1") or die(mysql_error());

if ($do_select)
{
    // Done select
    while ($selected_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($do_select))
    {
        // Show status
        echo $selected_data['status'];
    }
}

mysql_close($link);
?>          I tried some other before that, but i lost them. This is a result from search

Answer (score 2):

Try this::

```
Select count(online) from myTable where online=1
```

Comment: My problem is, i have absolutely no idea how to display this on a website.

Comment: That would suggest you don't have any website, cause if you don't know how to display this, then it's hard to believe your website is displaying anything ..

Comment: I do, it's y first time looking into PHP. At all.

Answer (score 2):

Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `rows` FROM `users` WHERE online = 1;
```

Then you would just use `fetch_row_assoc` or whatever, and echo `$result_set['rows']`;

Comment: I know i am asking for much, but could you post a full script? This really confuses me :S

Comment: Nah dude, just go Google it. There are many tutorials around that will help you with this.

Comment: As i said, i've literally been searching for hours and all i ended up in was confusion. I understand that you don't feel like helping me though.

Comment: Oh, I am very ready to help you, but not to spoonfeed you. You probably ended up in confusion because you:
a) didn't read
b) don't have ambition to learn

Comment: Can you then try explain me how to use the "fetch_row_assoc" and ill try myself.

Comment: Exactly how all the docs explain it. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php